# LRU Caching policy of a Node Query cache in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, caching

I have a elasticsearch cluster set up with node query cache enabled, I have set the size of the cache to be 2gb, but I am not completely sure how the LRU caching policy works in this case.

I have a query context run against the elasticsearch index and i expect the result to be cached, so that when there is request for the same query context again - there should be increase in the hit_count, but this is not the behavior i see in ES.

These are the stats of my query_cache

```
memory_size_in_bytes: 7176480,
total_count: 36605,
hit_count: 15657,
miss_count: 20948,
cache_size: 130,
cache_count: 130,
evictions: 0
```

Even though the memory_size_in_bytes is not reached its max. The result of the query context is not completely cached and when the same query context is fired against the elasticsearch index i see miss counts stats getting increased rather than hit counts.

Can anyone please explain about how the node query caching works in ES.